# Limit of fraction of functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been looking to find properties of limits regarding existence and non-existence of limits, but the only thing I could find is limits relating to sum and product of functions as such as here: [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562938/if-two-limits-dont-exist-are-we-sure-the-limit-of-sum-doesnt-exist)

Suppose that $f,g$ are functions and that $\lim f$ doesn't exist, but $\lim g$ does and $g(x_0) \ne 0$. Then what can be said about $\lim \frac{f}{g}$? Does it also not exist?

I know that this too can be seen as a product ($f \times \frac{1}{g}$), and I tried to find a counterexample similar to the answer in the link above, but I can't seem to find a function $g$ that will make $\lim \frac{f}{g}$ exist.

Comment: Suppose that it exists. Then $\lim \frac fg \cdot \lim g = \ldots$

Comment: @ajr Why multiply with $\lim g$?

Comment: @ajr You mean if both these limits exist, then the product also exists..So $\lim \frac{f}{g} \lim g=\lim f$ but $\lim f$ doesn't exist. $\implies \lim \frac{f}{g}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: The point he's making is that if $\lim {f\over g}$ exist then $\lim {f\over g} \cdot \lim g = \lim f$ hence $\lim f$ exists and we have a contradition.

Comment: @Furrane Many thanks

Comment: No problem, that's what I'm guessing though, it looks like it makes sense but I'm not entirely sure you can do those kind of operations on limits.